# How to change PHP WWW-Authenticate appearance and behaviour?

Tags: php

I have two questions regarding the WWW-Authenticate header from PHP. In my WebApp the username is the e-mail you registered with. Is it possible to change the string "Username" to "E-Mail" in the popup header? Furthermore the app crashes when you hit cancel so we did `echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';` to help, but is there a smoother way to handle the hit on the cancel button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where's your code ?

Comment: `header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');` It's basically just the standard header for authentication.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to customize the browser's authentication dialog. Use an HTML login page instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the behavior of `WWW-Authenticate`.
The best you can do is to create a form and redirect to the protected area,
something like:

**Html:**

```
<form action="validation.php" method="post">
User email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
User password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pass">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**validation.php**

```
<?php
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : die("no email");
$pass = !empty($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : die("no password);
header("Location: http://$email:$pass@website/directory/");
```